# App to view my iOS photos with their filenames

Tags: ios, applications, photos

Is there an app for iOS where I can see all my photos from the iOS Photos app, with their filenames next to them? Preferably without duplicating the photos, but rather just mirroring them and showing the metadata associated with each photo.

Answer (score 2):

Document 5

[image]

Edit :

[Document 5 AppStore link](https://appsto.re/fr/Vw_Vv.i)

Comment: Does this require that I import each photo into the app before I can see the metadata, therefore requiring that I duplicate my photo library?

Comment: @gary The app is free, just give it a try.

Comment: @Gary No, you haven't to duplicate your library. You can just acces to your iPhone library and look at all your stuff instantly.

Comment: And @patrix is right, the app is free :)